# How to change the position of x ticks from outside of chart frame to inside to the chart frame?

Tags: positioning, ticks

I want to have the marks on the x axis at the same position as in the left plotted figure.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=7.5cm,
                    ymin=0,
                    xmin=0,
                    xlabel=Zeit t\,/\,min,
                    ytick={0,25,100,160,250},
                    ylabel=Temperatur T\,/\,$^{\circ}$C,]
            \addplot table[x=Zeit,y=Temperatur] {Daten/V27.csv};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
            width=7.5cm,
            symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
            xtick=data,
            ymin=4.5,
            ymax=6,
            xlabel=Probennummer,
            ylabel near ticks,
            %xlabel near ticks,            
            ylabel= Scherfestigkeit F\,/\,MPa,]

            \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {
                (1,5.30)
                (2,5.84)
                (3,5.64)
                (4,5.56)
                (5,4.69)
                (6,4.95)
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Aufgezeichnete typische stress--strain Kurve und Mittelwerte der Scherergebnisse}
\label{fig:anpress_scher}
\end{figure}
```

[image: actual result]
[image: wished result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could explain further what you want to achieve? You are not satisfied with the x ticks position on the bar charts and you would like them to be...? You are mentioning the ticks position of the left graphs but you do not have the same number of x ticks. Could you clarify a bit what you are looking for?

Comment: @LudovicC. I guess he wants the ticks to point into the axis instead of out, look at the annotations to the bottom right plot in the screenshot.

Comment: @LudovicC. The first picture (first row) presents obtained result. In the second row there is desired one.

Comment: First Thank you. yes the ticks of the bar chart are on the wrong position. i only want to say that on the left picture the marks are on the top of the axis and on the bar chart the marks are under the x axis. I want that the short lines are on top of the x axis line. Did you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes it became clearer when looking at the description of your pictures in the "code" of your question. You should maybe edit your question just to state that what you want is to have the ticks in the chart frame and not outside.

Comment: @LudovicC. you're right. I thougt the description of the pictures is shown in the post.

Comment: You should try to add `xtick align=inside,` in your code, for example before the `xtick=data,` line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the option `xtick align=inside` as recommended page 282 of the [pgfplots package documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

The MWE is now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=7.5cm,
                    ymin=0,
                    xmin=0,
                    xlabel=Zeit t\,/\,min,
                    ytick={0,25,100,160,250},
                    ylabel=Temperatur T\,/\,$^{\circ}$C,]
          %  \addplot table[x=Zeit,y=Temperatur] {Daten/V27.csv};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
            width=7.5cm,
            symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
            xtick align=inside,
            xtick=data,
            ymin=4.5,
            ymax=6,
            xlabel=Probennummer,
            ylabel near ticks,
            %xlabel near ticks,            
            ylabel= Scherfestigkeit F\,/\,MPa,]

            \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {
                (1,5.30)
                (2,5.84)
                (3,5.64)
                (4,5.56)
                (5,4.69)
                (6,4.95)
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Aufgezeichnete typische stress--strain Kurve und Mittelwerte der Scherergebnisse}
\label{fig:anpress_scher}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have commented the first `\addplot` command since I do not have the file to recreate your plot. And here is the output (obviously the left graph is empty):

[image: Output]

**NOTE** This option can be used in a more generic way for `ytick align`, `ztick align` or all at once `tick align` and the values possible are `inside`, `center` and `outside`. By defaults it should be `inside` but apparently in your case something changed it to `outside` for the x ticks.

**EDIT** It seems that the two graphs are not vertically aligned (the left one is slightly higher than the right one). I thought it was coming from the 6 y tick on the bar charts which is higher than the frame and then the left frame would be aligned with this value but it turned out that even with adding `ymax=6.2` and `ytick={4.5,5,5.5,6}` to the bar chart the frames are still not at the same height.

[image: Output 2]

Comment: it worked. But there is another trouble. I think you can see that the high of left and right graph are different in the document.  Do you know what i mean? the right graph begins a little bit under the left graph. They are on different positions and i do not know why.

Comment: I was also having some problems putting the xticks inside the chart. When using bar plots, the "xtick align = inside" must appear after "ybar".