# How to hide x ticks in pgf bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

how to move these red marked `ticks` to the inside of the box (like on the y axis)?

Thank you

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{anysize} % Für \marginsize
\marginsize{32mm}{32mm}{20mm}{24mm} % Seitenränder
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % Zeilenabstand

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\begin{axis}[
    axis x line*=box,
    axis y line*=box,
    tick align=inside,  %%already tried this one here!!
    width=14cm,
    height=6.75cm,
    xlabel=Platzhalter,
    xticklabel style={yshift=-0.1cm},
    ylabel=Platzhalter,
    yticklabel style={xshift=-0.1cm},
    label style={font={\small}},
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
    grid = both,
    grid style={line width=0.2pt,},
    legend style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        at={(0.5,1.03)},
        anchor=south,
        draw=none,
    },
    legend columns=5,
    legend cell align = right,
    ,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=5,
    xtick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    xticklabels={,2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, },
    ymin=0,
    ymax=14,
    ytick={0,2,...,14}, 
    ybar=8pt, %Abstand Säulen
    bar width=12pt, %Breite Säulen
  ] 

  \addplot[blue,fill=blue!30] plot coordinates 
    {(1, 6) (2, 8) (3, 5) (4, 13)};
  \addplot[red,fill=red!30] plot coordinates 
    {(1, 5) (2, 6) (3, 12) (4, 5)};
  \legend{Barplot 1, Barplot 2}
\end{axis}



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't want them to be removed. They should be moved inside the box.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I mixed your title and text to removing them.. well, anyway, then go for [How to change the position of x ticks from outside of chart frame to inside to the chart frame?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140927/100384)

Comment: Already tried this 'tick align=inside'. But this doesn't changes the ticks from the x axis.

Comment: You need to move the `tick align` option after the `ybar` option, because `ybar` resets the `tick align`.

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thank you (https://media.giphy.com/media/1Z02vuppxP1Pa/giphy.gif)