# Direction of axis ticks in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

When plotting a bar chart using the following example, the ticks of the y axis are directed to the inside, the ones of the x axis to the outside. How can I make it so they both show on the inside and outside of the chart?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[ybar,symbolic x coords={A,B,C},xtick={A,B,C}]
     \addplot coordinates{(A,24)(B,25)(C,26)};
     \addplot coordinates{(A,17)(B,19)(C,21)};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, and welcome to tex.SX. It generally increases the probability of getting an answer if you post a complete code example (usually `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` ... `\begin{document}`... etc.) this way we can just copy and paste your code and start playing around with it to find a solution

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please post a full minimal example instead of a sniplet like this as it makes it a lot easier for others to test your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140937/3929, plus looked up the options for `xtick align` and guessed that there is also an option that sets both.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    xtick={A,B,C},
    tick align=center, % <------
    ]
    \addplot coordinates{(A,24)(B,25)(C,26) };
    \addplot coordinates{(A,17)(B,19)(C,21)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cheesus for a lot of tikz/pgfplots questions, you can get the answer via google and trying to guess what it is called in English. It is highly likely that someone has asked about it before.