# Is it possible to remove the ticks marks on the bottom and top of my bar graph? I don't like how they look outside

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar width=1cm,
    enlargelimits=0.2,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Average Hardness Value [HV1]},
    symbolic x coords={Untreated, Carburized$^1$, Carburized$^2$},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords, 
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    x tick label style={rotate=0, anchor=north}
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(Untreated,129.5) (Carburized$^1$,631.1) (Carburized$^2$,506.6)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Agh sorry I don't know why the spacing is weird

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140927/47927 , or use `xtick style={draw=none}´ to remove them completely.

Comment: Regarding code markup here on the site: select the code and hit Ctrl + K, or click the button marked `{}`. Code blocks will be indented with four spaces, inline code placed between backticks.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you so much!!